# How to use a none delimiter with csv.writer?

Tags: python, csv, delimiter, writer, csvwriter

I'm creating a discord bot in python and I want to have a log system for the warn command. To set up this, I'm using a .csv file in which I write all the information I want about a user.

It's the first time I use .csv, so to manipulate the data, I take the content of the file and convert it into a list of list. One sublist = one line of the table.

After treatment, I put all the elements of each sublists side by side, separated by a ";" to store it properly in the .csv file.

The problem I have comes from this :

```
csvwriter = csv.writer(wfile, delimiter=";")
```

For each caracter in the final file, a ";" is put right after so instead of this : (abc;def;ghi), I have this : (a;b;c;d;...).

All of the code :

```
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_any_role(765280296781742090, 765609632482721852, 882222368976670772)
    async def test(self, ctx, member:discord.Member):

        messages = await ctx.channel.history(limit = 1).flatten()
        for each_message in messages:
            await each_message.delete()

        with open("ressources/logs/warn_logs.csv", 'r', newline='') as csvfile:

            content = []
            new_registrated = []

            is_registrated = False

            for line in csvfile:
                line = line.split(";")
                content.append(line)

            for cell in content:
                if cell == content[0]:
                    pass
                else:
                    if int(cell[0]) == int(member.id):
                        is_registrated = True
                        cell[3] = int(cell[3])+1
                        cell[3] = str(cell[3])
                    
            if is_registrated == False:

                new_registrated.append(str(member.id))
                new_registrated.append(str(member._user))
                new_registrated.append(member.nick)
                new_registrated.append("1\r\n") 

                content.append(new_registrated)

            with open("ressources/logs/warn_logs.csv", 'w', newline='') as wfile:
                csvwriter = csv.writer(wfile, delimiter=";")
                
                # for line in content:
                #     print(line)
                #     line = ";".join(line)
                #     print(line)
                #     csvwriter.writerow(line)

                csvwriter.writerow("abc")
                

            wfile.close()

        csvfile.close()
```

What I have :
[image: What I have :]

What I want :
[image: What I want :]

I'm working on it for a while now so if someone could help me, I would be very greatful.

NB: I'm French, and my English isn't perfect so don't hesitate to correct me

I tried to:

- Not put the delimiter : the ";" became ","
- Put delimiter="smth" / =False / =None : it doesn't work
- Any other character : ";" became any other character

Comment: The `.writerow()` method wants an *entire row* to be written, in the form of a list or tuple of items - NOT just a single string (which gets interpreted as a sequence of individual characters).

Comment: I tried to put a list, but it wrote the entiere list (including the [ ]) I'm gonna try it anyways

Answer (score 1):

The `writerow()` function expects an iterable object to write a whole row.

```
csvwriter.writerow("abc")
```

will write to the file:

```
a;b;c
```

and

```
csvwriter.writerow(["abc", "def"])
```

will write:

```
abc;def
```

If `line` is a list of strings then `line = ";".join(line)` is wrong, `line` should go directly to `writerow()`. The whole point of using a `csv` module in **not to** think about delimiters.

Also if you are using a `with open(...) as f:` you don't have to close the file.

Comment: Ok I didn't that. For now I have a list of list but with a loop, I can solve my problem